# Ubuntu Studio 19.04: How to use BlueTooth headphones with JACK?

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-studio, jack, lmms

So, I've installed Ubuntu Studio on a laptop, and gotten LMMS working with JACK. I was also able to pair a set of BlueTooth Headphones with Studio. However, it seems LMMS won't play audio to the BT 'phones. It keeps playing out the laptop speakers.

How do I get it to play to the headphones? Or is that simply not possible with JACK? Perhaps JACK does not support BT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jack cannot support Bluetooth headphones. Bluetooth headphone support is handled exclusively by PulseAudio (not even ALSA).

The reason for Jack not supporting Bluetooth audio devices is primarily because Jack is for low latency professional audio, and Bluetooth adds a lot of latency. Basically, it's outside of the scope of the project altogether.

Comment: Thanks - I suspected that might be the case - that BT has too much latency.

Comment: Latency is not an issue while working with DAW (editing, mixing or mastering). Also - aptX has its low latency version which ensures such low latency that even work with instruments is posible.

Comment: @pt12lol Still doesn't change that Jack doesn't support Bluetooth.